# useRole: yarn start = passed, yarn build = failed

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
import { Role } from 'testcafe';

const admin = Role('http://localhost:3000' ,async t => {    // port: 5000 when yarn build
  await t
      .typeText('#login', 'admin')
      .typeText('#password', '923878')
      .click('#submit-button')
}
 , { preserveUrl: true }
); 

fixture `Test for profile`;

test('Test for user name', async t => {
    await t
      .useRole(admin)
      .click('#avatar')
      .expect('#user-name').eql('admin');
  });
```

If i use 'yarn start', this test:

1. Open page.
2. Authorized.
3. Refresh page.
4. Walks in steps.

If i use 'yarn build', this test:

1. Open page.
2. Authorized.
3. Refresh page.
4. The main page is displayed.
5. The user is not logged in.

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient to determine the cause of the issue. Could you send us your package.json scripts for the 'start' and 'build' commands?

I suppose that the issue can be related to the application. In this case, I will also need the problematic application or a small sample, which I can run to examine the issue and find its cause. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "start": "TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true react-scripts start",
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false react-scripts build",

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, the information you provided is insufficient to determine the cause of the issue. It will be better if you provide your entire sample application where we can see the described behavior. See if you can share one. You can also submit a bug report to the official testcafe repo at [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md).